# 'Outlet' property of routing not working in angular6+

Tags: angular, routes

I have 3 navigation tabs and I am trying to load components that are part of different modules to different `<router-outlet>`

`Tab0Component,Tab1Component component` is a part of storedashboardModule and `storedashboardModule` is lazily loaded. Just loading `storedashboardModule` first and routing to `tab0` initially.

Trying to route to `store/tab0` for  `tab0` initially and when `tab1` is clicked route to `route/tab1`

Stackblitz link:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbyemp?file=src/app/customers/customers.module.ts

## app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

## app.routing.ts

```
Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'store/tab0',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: CmnLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'store',
                loadChildren: () => import('./store-dashboard/store-dashboard.module').then(m => m.storedashboardModule)
            },
            {
                path: 'search',
                loadChildren: () => import('./custom-components/custom-components.module').then(m => m.CustomComponentsModule)
            }           
        ]
    }  
];
```

## storedashboardModule.routing.ts

```
Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tab0',
        component: Tab0Component,
         outlet: "tab0",
        data: {
            title: 'tab0'
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'tab1',
        component: Tab1Component,
        outlet: "tab1",
        data: {
            title: 'tab1'
        }
    }
];
```

## CmnLayoutComponent.html

```
<router-outlet name="tab0"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="tab1"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="search"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: In your `app.routing.ts`, I don't think you need the *first* object in the routes array `Routes`

Comment: Trying to route to   'store/tab0'  when app Loads initially.

Comment: But why is it lazily loaded then?

Comment: Tab0Component,Tab1Component component is a part of storedashboardModule and storedashboardModule is lazily loaded. Just loading storedashboardModule first and routing to tab0 initially.

Comment: My guess is that at first it `''` redirects to `'store/tab0'`, but your second route also is looking for `''` so it doesn't find it. Possible to add a stackblitz?

Comment: It does not working even if  {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'store/tab0',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    }, is inside children array.

Comment: Updated stackblitz

Comment: Does this need to be done using only the `outlet` property?

Comment: Currently, yes...but the issue is why 'outlet' not working here. Is something missing or there exists bug in router.

Comment: Well, not sure of that and I don't think I can assist you as I've used till angular 7's routing only.

Comment: Is it related to angular version 8 or  7.

Comment: I doubt its an issue with angular 8; there maybe something wrong that we are doing